# Dynamically calculate average value no matter what type of values (integer, Timestamp, etc.)

Tags: c#, reflection, timestamp, extension-methods

I have a dynamic method `GetAverage()` using reflection to calculate an average value for a list of string values. The string values are dynamically converted to a type determined in `ValueType`. The type `DataSet` contains a `List<string>`:

```
public class AggregateController {     

    private List<DataSet> DataSets { get; set; }

    private Type ValueType { get; set; }

    public string GetAverage () {
        dynamic sum = Activator.CreateInstance(this.ValueType);

        this.DataSets.ForEach(x => {
            sum += this.TransformInputValue(x[0]);
        });

        return sum.Average().ToString();              
    }

    private dynamic TransformInputValue (string value) {
        try {
            var mI = this.ValueType.GetMethod("Parse", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
            return (dynamic)mI.Invoke(this, new object[] { value });
        } catch {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This method does everything perfectly when the given values are numeric values. Now I want to achieve dynamically calculating average values for timestamp values with the same method. The problem is that there is no `Average()` extension method for TimeStamp objects and I do not mean to additionally implement a condition checking for timestamp values like this:

```
if (this.ValueType == typeof(TimeStamp)) {
    //do stuff to calculate TimeStamp average.
} else {
    return sum.Average().ToString();
}
```

Is there a way to dynamically react to types like `TimeStamp` which have no `Average()` extension method?

Comment: You are calling transform method for each item in the list, consider to check for type only once before starting iterating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own **Extension method** -> [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977(v=vs.110).aspx).
Just write extension method for TimeStamp.

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't know why, but I didn't concerned that

Answer (score 1):

How about writing your own extensions to the types you want an Average for.

For example:

```
private static string Average(this ClassYouWantaAverageFor foo) 
{
    // calculate the average
    return "average";
}
```

Your `sum.Average().ToString()` should take the new extension.